# Offline file version control (preferably with PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, version-control, cron, versioning

How can I control changes in some files on my local machine WITHOUT using Git or any other online version control services?

Is there some utility that tracks changes in files and in case of change, for example, backups old version of file in some special folder? Or maybe it is possible to perform that kind of action with PHP, Laravel project, custom console command, crontab job?

Basically I need to force on some files something similar to that situation when you change .env file in project and .env~ file appears.

Comment: If you're into overkill solutions you could always use something like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), or [Puppet](https://puppet.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is not an online version control. You can work with it offline and then optionally push changes to a remote server of choice.

You commit your changes when you feel like this is a good time to take a snapshot of your project using `git commit`. Each commit has an id so that if you need to rollback to a previous stage of your project you could do so like `git reset <commit_id>` or maybe `git revert <commit_id>`. Atlassian gives a very good detailed documentation as to how you can undo changes [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes).

Add to that all the powerful features that git provides like branching, tagging and all.

Answer (score 3):

In Git you can work completely offline .if you don't give remote urls like origin it will be in your system locally. just say git init in that folder that you want plus don't give origin

Comment: okay, but what if I already have .git configs in my project folder? Can I create some kind of local branch (if "master" branch is online git repo, and, for example, "dev" branch will be stored locally)?

Comment: I think you need to read this  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols .